# Heterogeneous container with dynamic access

Tags: c++, containers, heterogeneous

I am looking for a heterogeneous container that allows dynamic access at runtime. Is that even possible? Is there any library that implements such a feature?

Comment: Would you care to define any of your terms and to give a small, representative usage example?

Comment: Something like a [`std::vector<std::any>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)?

Comment: @KerrekSB I am just asking out of sheer curiosity :)

Comment: It's a trade off with type constraints, the more dynamic the request the less types can be guaranteed. It ranges from typeless stuff similar to `void *` to the actual type of your data.